# How do can i solve the integral, finding cdf

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with mean 1 and Y a uniform random variable between $0$ and $1$.

Assume X and Y are independent and let $Z =e^{X/2}$

Find the joint cumulative distribution function of $(X,Y), F(X\leq x,Y\leq y)$.

Comment: You should show your attempt.  You need to know the definition of the things involved: exponential random variable, uniform random variable, independent.  There is no need to mention $Z$ for this question.

Comment: fx(x)=e^-x,fy(y)=1 ,fx,y(x,y)=e^-x, 0/1 x/∞ (e^-x) dx dy = 1-e^-1,this is my sol,

Comment: @JustBelieve Please use MathJax.  $$\begin{align}f_X(x)~=~&e^{-x} \mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\infty)} \\[2ex] f_Y(y)~=~&\mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1]}, \\[2ex] F_{X,Y}(x,y) ~=~& \int_0^x f_X(s)\operatorname d s\cdot \int_0^y f_Y(t)\operatorname d t\cdot \mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\infty)}\mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1]} \\[1ex] ~=~& (1-e^{-x})\cdot \mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\infty)}\mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1]}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: This is particularly easy since $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Because of independence, 
$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_{X}(x)F_{Y}(y)$$
for all $x, y$.

It should not be particularly difficult for you to compute these CDFs.

Comment: the problem is, will the integral for x from x to infinity or not, ....Thanks alot for you

Comment: @Justbelieve What integral?

Comment: @Gramham Kemp                                    f(x,y) to get F(x,y)  ⇨cdf   ⇨               And why interval of x is not [x,∞
]?        ••Thanks